# Why can't I have a shadow by pointlight in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I want to have shadows, I set as follows, really wondering what's the problem? I have a grid, with cubic and sphere as a child of it, and also I set the castShadow and Receive shadow for them but it has no result for shadow.
some parts of my code:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, dice, dice1;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
// Z is up for objects intended to be 3D printed.
camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
scene.add(camera);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor(0x999999);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0x000000, 1, 1000);
light.position.set(10, 10,10);
light.castShadow = true; // default false
scene.add(light);
//Set up shadow properties for the light;
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024; // default
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024; // default
light.shadow.camera.near = 1; // default
light.shadow.camera.far = 1000 // default
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 50, 0xffffff, 0x555555);
grid.colorGrid = 0x00ff00;
grid.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
scene.add(grid);
objects.push(grid); // add to the array for DragControls
grid.receiveShadow=true;
//Create a sphere that cast shadows (but does not receive them)
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
sphere.castShadow = true; //default is false
sphere.receiveShadow = false; //default
sphere.position.set(10, 15, 10);
scene.add(sphere);
//initializing the color cubic
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0xff0000});
dice = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1), material);
dice.position.set(10, 2.5, 10);
dice.castShadow = true;
grid.add(dice);
```

Comment: Add a `PointLightHelper` to help visualize your `PointLight` and see if your objects fall within the cone.

Comment: @gaitat I can drag my plane , so I can see , although it falls into the cone, the shadow doesn't appear.

Comment: can you create a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: yes, ofcourse. in this fiidle I haven't uploaded my amf object, and it can't be zoomed or dragged (it is ok in my own prj), but the issue is about shadow which can not be seen, unfortunately. @gaitat
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Zahraaa/mfrk9gt8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast shadow on a grid. it is just lines.
Add this in your code to see shadows.

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,50), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00 }));
plane.castShadow = false;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.position.set(0, 0, -1);
scene.add(plane);
```

Comment: That's it. Thank u a lot.